# Increasing Sequence of Sets and Difference

Tags: probability

If $A_i\subset A_{i+1},$ why is that under a probability measure space, we have $P(A_{i+1}-A_{i})=P(A_{i+1})-P(A_{i})?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For notation I just assume $A\subset B$.

Then $B = (B\setminus A) \cup A $ and this union is disjoint
so:

$P(B) = P(B\setminus A) + P(A)$.

So, $P(B\setminus A) = P(B) - P(A)$.

Comment: so very obvious, but I missed it. haha thanks!

Comment: happens to everyone :) 
no problem